# Any common library for Wallet and smart contract in android,IOS and Web?

Tags: go-ethereum, android, ios

Before post this question I researched about Ethereum wallet and smart contract.
I saw many of the libraries which support android & iOS in different protocol, but not in a same protocol. So, I am expecting the libraries from same protocol(ie., I need a common library for all three platforms).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find one that's worth using except cross-platform libs. I suggest you run a node using [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) and communicate with it via [JSON RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC). It's pretty simple and it won't take long to implement the requests you'll need for a wallet.